# I can't make a DELETE with CORS and AngularJS

Tags: http, angularjs, cors, access-control

I'm trying to make a DELETE request with AngularJS.

I'm sending this headers from the Server:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE');
```

But in Chrome, when I do an

```
$http({method: 'DELETE', url: EmployeesURL + "remove/id/" + id})
```

it throws a *Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.* error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an 's'  Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: Damn, I know the issue was a super stupid thing! 
Thanks man!