# All of a sudden I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error

Tags: angularjs

I have a Angular service that requests a JSON output from themoviedb.org and it always worked, but today I suddenly got an error in my console.

This is the service,

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('MovieSearch',

    function($http, $q){
      return{
        search: function(searchquery){
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
          var service = '/search/movie';
          var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
          var search = searchquery
          var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
          var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;


          $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              if (status == 200) {
                deferred.resolve(data.results);

              } else {
                console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              }

            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              deferred.resolve(false);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    })

})();
```

And this is the error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The error is occuring inside the JSON output,

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=James%20Bond%20Spectre&callback=angular.callbacks._2

It's likely themoviedb changed something, but I'm wondering if there's something to be done on my side to fix it. A lot of posts advice to add `JSON_CALLBACK` but I've already done so. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You aren't asking for JSON output, you're asking for JSONP but you're getting JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS resource service with jsonp fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397254/angularjs-resource-service-with-jsonp-fails)

Comment: idk, simple http get works http://plnkr.co/edit/AccJXFf7gvCEoSdT33vO?p=preview

Comment: It seemed it was a bug on the side of themoviedb, they fixed it and it's back to working.